# Inherited Abstract colour - Confused?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

Error picture 1
[image: Error picture 1]

Error picture 2
[image: Error picture 2]

Hello, I keep getting this error and i completely do not understand, any help would be greatyly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: All relevant I formation much be posted here directly as text. Also I clude what you've already tried to solve the problem.

Comment: In picture 1 the first two proposals are solutions for the same error which is shown in picture 2 as the first of two markers of line 6. See the answers below, why this error is shown and for details to the proposed solutions.

Answer (score 2):

[Iterable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) is an *interface*, a special reference type in Java that defines a contract of methods that must be implemented by all classes that implement it.

In the case of `Iterable`, there is one such method, [iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#iterator--). This method returns an Iterator object, which will define the exact nature of the iteration over instances of your class.

For this reason, trying to add `implements Iterable<Name>` to your class without specifying an implementation for the `iterator()` method results in a compilation error.

Another option is declaring the class as an *abstract class* by adding the `abstract` keyword before `class` in the class declaration. 
Instances of abstract classes cannot be created directly, so abstract classes do not have to directly implement methods from interfaces. However, any class that inherits from such an abstract class will have to implement methods from this interface or be declared abstract as well.

---

In your specific case, the answer will depend on the code of your class and your requirements. I encourage you to edit your question with the code of your Register class, so a more specific solution can be suggested.
If you store `Name` objects in the `Register` class inside a list (or any other [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) data structure) this could be as simple as using the iterator method of the list:

```
public class Register implements Iterable<Name> {

    private List<Name> allNames = new List<>();

    @Override
        public Iterator<Name> iterator() {
            return allNames.iterator();
        }
}
```

This works because in this case the List class already contains an implementation for the `iterator()` method, and so it can be called directly.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is saying that you must implement `Iterator<String> iterator()` method or make Register class abstract and implement `Iterator<String> iterator()` method some where down lower in the inheritance chain.

Meaning that if you want to Register class to be iterable, you must comply with its contract and provide a way to get iterator for this class.

In the `Iterator<String> iterator()` implementation you should provide an iterator itself. And one of the way to do it is to return the iterator from your private list class member, something like this might do:

```
public class Register implements Iterable<Name> {

    private List<Name> names = new ArrayList<Name>();

    @Override
    public Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return names.iterator();
    }

}
```